# Date Parse converting PM to AM

Tags: android, date

In the following code myLeg.TimeStamp is a String that has "Feb 26 2014 12:31:23 PM"
myRTleg.Tstamp is a Date.

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy HH:mm:ss a");
myRTleg.TStamp = formatter.parse(myLeg.TimeStamp);
String debugStr = myRTleg.TStamp.toString();
```

DebugStr has the same exact date in it but it has AM instead of PM !!

Why is it doing this?
Thanks,
Dean

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From 
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

H   Hour in day (0-23)
...
h   Hour in am/pm (1-12)

so try
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy hh:mm:ss a");

The AM/PM is probably defaulting to AM, and being ignored because the hours are HH (military) instead of hh

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide the full input and output dates. Check the timezone of your input date and output date to see if they are different. It could just be the same date in time but formatted in using different time zones.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use hh for hours instead of HH. HH is used for Military time.